# Error 'list' object is not callable, in discord.py 1.6.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have been coding this command for discord.py for a little bit, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why I am getting the error; list object is not callable

```py
    async def classify(self, mph):
        global classification
        if mph > 39:
            classification = "Tropical Storm"
        if mph > 74:
            classification = "Hurricane"
        if mph > 110:
            classification = "Major Hurricane"
        return classification

    @commands.command(aliases=['generate_season'])
    async def generateseason(self, ctx):
        global hurricane_amount
        global acceptable
        hurricane_list_combined = objectfile.twentytwentyhurricanelist + objectfile.greekhurricanelist
        hurricane_num = 0
        la_nina_or_el_nino = random.choice(['La Nina', 'El Nino'])
        chance = random.randint(1, 100)
        acceptable = await objectfile.acceptable(chance)
        if la_nina_or_el_nino == 'La Nina':
            hurricane_amount = random.randint(5, 37)
        if la_nina_or_el_nino == 'El Nino':
            hurricane_amount = random.randint(2, 13)
        hurricane_list_one = ""
        hurricane_list_two = ""
        hurricane_list_three = ""
        hurricane_list_four = ""
        pages = 0
        page_list = []
        for _ in range(hurricane_amount):
            mph = random.choice(acceptable)
            kph = round(mph / 1.151)
            if 0 <= hurricane_num <= 10:
                hurricane_list_one += f"{await self.classify(mph)} {hurricane_list_combined[hurricane_num]}, with {mph} mph winds ({kph} kph winds)\n"
            if 10 <= hurricane_num <= 20:
                hurricane_list_two += f"{await self.classify(mph)} {hurricane_list_combined[hurricane_num]}, with {mph} mph winds ({kph} kph winds)\n"
            if 20 <= hurricane_num <= 30:
                hurricane_list_three += f"{await self.classify(mph)} {hurricane_list_combined[hurricane_num]}, with {mph} mph winds ({kph} kph winds)\n"
            if 30 <= hurricane_num <= 40:
                hurricane_list_four += f"{await self.classify(mph)} {hurricane_list_combined[hurricane_num]}, with {mph} mph winds ({kph} kph winds)\n"
            hurricane_num += 1
        if hurricane_num < 0:
            page_list.append(objectfile.twoembed("2020 generated Hurricane season",
                                                 hurricane_list_one))
        if hurricane_num < 10:
            page_list.append(objectfile.twoembed("2020 generated Hurricane season",
                                                 hurricane_list_two))
        if hurricane_num < 20:
            page_list.append(objectfile.twoembed("2020 generated Hurricane season",
                                                 hurricane_list_three))
        if hurricane_num < 30:
            page_list.append(objectfile.twoembed("2020 generated Hurricane season",
                                                 hurricane_list_four))
        await ctx.send(embed=page_list[pages])
```

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. I haven't had this error before while dealing with lists so I don't know why this is going on.
The reason why there is a pages variable is that I am going to try to paginate it using custom pagination however it does not work even when I replace `[pages]` with `[0]`

Comment: Could you please provide the actual traceback so that we can see what line it comes from?

Comment: "list not callable" means are you doing `my_list(something)` like you would a function. Lists can't be called though, so you probably meant to use `[ ]` instead of `( )` somewhere